# Spring Boot pooling database connection with multipledatabase

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, connection-pooling, multi-database

I'm trying to configure a multi database applications with pool of connections.
I've denifed datasource beans in my application.properties:

```
# Topology and Configuration Datasource.
spring.datasource.tc.url=jdbc:postgresql://10.10.10.10:5432/TopologyConfiguration
spring.datasource.tc.username=adminsitraenr
spring.datasource.tc.password=abc123
spring.datasource.tc.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

# Versions Datasource.
spring.datasource.v.url=jdbc:postgresql://10.10.10.10:5432/Versions
spring.datasource.v.username=adminsitraenr
spring.datasource.v.password=abc123
spring.datasource.v.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

# Transportation Datasource.
spring.datasource.tp.url=jdbc:postgresql://10.10.10.10:5432/TransportPlan
spring.datasource.tp.username=adminsitraenr
spring.datasource.tp.password=abc123
spring.datasource.tp.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=2
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=15
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=8
spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=true
```

Then I've created 3 configuration classes to define each datasource:

```
public class TopologyConfigurationDbConfig {

  /**
   * datasourceproperties creation method
   * @return datasourceproperties
   */
  @Primary
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.tc")
  public DataSourceProperties tcDSProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
  }

  /**
   * datasourceproperties creation method
   * @param tcDSProperties datasource properties
   * @return datasource
   */
  @Primary
  @Bean
  public DataSource tcDS(@Qualifier("tcDSProperties") DataSourceProperties tcDSProperties) {
    return tcDSProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().build();
  }

  /**
   * LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean creation method
   * @param tcDS datasource
   * @param builder entity manager factory builder
   * @return localcontainterentitymanagerfactorybean
   */
  @Primary
  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean tcEMFactory(@Qualifier("tcDS") DataSource tcDS,
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
    return builder.dataSource(tcDS).packages("com.sitraplus.router.topologyconfiguration.domain").build();
  }

  /**
   * Platform transaction manager creation method
   * @param tcEMFactory entity manager factory
   * @return platformtransactionmanager
   */
  @Primary
  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager tcDSTransactionManager(@Qualifier("tcEMFactory") EntityManagerFactory tcEMFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(tcEMFactory);
  }
```

As you can see I've established data source type and other parameters to configure my connection pool but when I run my application the number of connections is always 10. ¿Any idea?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you specifying @Primary annotations in the others configuration ds' classes? Whether is yes, remove them and just keep it in the main ds class

Comment: No, I don't. @Primary annotations are only in this configuration class.